# Interactive button on a floor map

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, canvas

I'm trying to search information about how to create an interactive floor map  (I think I could use a blueprint as a background image) with interactive buttons in some specific areas (in the meeting rooms) that change the colour depending on their availability.
The room's availability will be checked with an HTTP POST to a service that I will create but my main problem is that I don't find any information about how to create those buttons on the image. I would like that those buttons show a small text box with some information about the rooms, meetings info, etc.
Could somebody recommend me any documentation, guide, tutorial o whatever? Maybe are there some js libraries that I could use.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I would use SVG or HTML `<map>` for this. You can use an image as a background  and you can map every room using SVG paths or polygonal hot areas - if you opt for `<map>`.  [MDN map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/map)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://static.planetminecraft.com/files/resource_media/screenshot/1326/qmblock_5813523_lrg.jpg" alt="room layout">
  <button onclick="changeBackground(this)">Click me</button>
</div>
<script>
  let changeBackground = (ele) => {
    let bg = ele.style.background;
    ele.style.background = bg === 'red' ? 'transparent' : 'red';
  }
</script>
<style>
  div {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 240px;
    margin: auto;
  }
  
  img {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  button {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: transparent;
    border: none
  }
</style>
```